# Plotly: using dictionary to assign colors is not working & hover info not correct

Tags: python, dictionary, histogram, plotly, plotly-dash

I have created the histogram on the dash, if i choose project names from dropdown menu, the histogram changes based on phases of projectcs, now i would like to assign colors for each phases of projects, otherwise it will assign colors randomly. My second issue is the hover text of histogram. My output is as following:
[image] 
So in this output if i chose prj-1, prj2 from dropdown menu. i see 3 phases which belong to selected projects. But the hover text for phase3 shown as 'phase1'. And the colors for three bars are the same even i created the dictionary for colors which i tried with following lines, but as a result i see only one color for all bars in histogram. :

```
color_dict = {'phase1': '#9400D3', 'phase2': '#32CD32', 'phase3': '#FF8000','phase4': '#4682B4'}
marker': {
            'color': color_dict
        }
```

but if i use colors as a list it works but it set the colors to random labels:

```
    marker': {
            'color': ['#9400D3','#32CD32', '#FF8000','#4682B4']
        }
```

And my output would be: 
[image]
It is almost my desired output, but still hover text is wrong and the colors assigned randomly, i would like for example to assign green to phase1, purple to phase2 and etc. using dictionary as i put example above.
here is the full code:

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
def gantt_fig(df,val):
    if isinstance(val, str):
        df = df.loc[df['prjID']==val]
    else:
        df = df[df['prjID'].isin(val)]
    return df
df = pd.DataFrame({'prjID': ['prj-1', 'prj-1','prj-2', 'prj-2', 'prj-2','prj-3', 'prj-3', 'prj-4'],
               'prjPhase': ['phase1', 'phase2','phase1', 'phase3', 'phase2', 'phase2','phase1', 'phase4']})
options = df['prjID'].unique()
activities = df['prjPhase'].unique()
app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(id='my-dropdown',options=[{'label': name, 'value': name} for name in options],
        value=options[0], multi=True),
    dcc.Graph(id='my-graph')])

@app.callback(Output('my-graph', 'figure'), [Input('my-dropdown', 'value')])
def update_graph(dropdownproject):
    fig = gantt_fig(df, dropdownproject)
    df2= fig
    color_dict = {'phase1': '#9400D3', 'phase2': '#32CD32', 'phase3': '#FF8000','phase4': '#4682B4'}
    figure = {
        'data': [
        {
            'x': df2['prjPhase'],
            'text': df2['prjPhase'],
            'type': 'histogram',
            'marker': {
                'color': color_dict
            }}]}
    return figure
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Thanks.

Comment: You may know what you're working with but we don't, for these kinds of question you should post what you're getting and what do you expect to get, otherwise is hard to have enough information.

Comment: yes you are right, sorry. I edit the question. please kindly see the edited version. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not quite sure of what you're trying, but here's what's happening:

If you take a look at `df2['prjPhase']` you will see

```
>>> df2['prjPhase']
0    phase1
1    phase2
2    phase1
3    phase3
4    phase2
Name: prjPhase, dtype: object
```

so when using a histogram, `'x': df2['prjPhase']` will count the **occurrences** of each unique value in that series. As there are 3 different values the X-axis will have 3 bins and by doing `'text': df2['prjPhase']` you're passing 5 values to these bins, hence the wrong names.

`'text': df2['prjPhase'].unique()` would be more adequate (still I would check the order that this yields) and as for the color, `'color': [color_dict[x] for x in df2['prjPhase'].unique()]` would make sure the right color is used in each trace (if you only put the list the color would be wrong if there's a `phase4` occurrence without a `phase3` one for instance).

If you're working with gantt charts I would also take a look at plotly's [figure factory gantt charts](https://plot.ly/python/gantt/).

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. Could you please explain why the following line:
`color_dict = {'phase1': '#9400D3', 'phase2': '#32CD32', 'phase3': 
    '#FF8000','phase4': '#4682B4'}
    marker': {
            'color': color_dict
        }
`
    
which is the colors as a dictionary - did not work. Even it did not throw me an error, just showed the histogram in same color. But the following line worked: 

   `'color': [color_dict[x] for x in df2['prjPhase'].unique()]` 

worked.

Comment: In the [docs](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#histogram-marker-color) for histogram.marker.color it says that takes either a specific color or an array. It would be nice if it could take a mapping but it's not implemented, the fact that it doesn't throw an error could be because dictionaries share most of lists' methods, which usually act upon the keys of the dictionary as if they were a list. As in your case the keys were not colors plotly used the default color.

Comment: @vlizana if you have free time, kindly check this. somewhat similar to this. I'm stuck with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65187333/set-python-plotly-colors-according-to-a-list